# Keep references when creating numPy arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose the following code:

```
x = np.array([3,2])
y = [x,x]
z = np.array(y)
```

now z has two different copies of x which are different from the original x as well:

> x[0] = 10
>
> y
>
> [array([10,  2]), array([10,  2])]
>
> z
>
> array([[3, 2],
>          [3, 2]])

I need to save memory by just make z contains references to x not a copy of it, how to do it in numPy?

Comment: If you want read-only copies, use `np.broadcast_to`.

Comment: Is the [x,x] duplicate meaningful, or just part of the example?  How about `np.array([x,y,z])`?

Comment: An object dtype array can contain arrays (or other objects) in basically the same ways as a list does.  Math operations are slower, if they work at all.